# How can use the label object of one form into other form

Tags: .net, user-interface

actually i just want to set the status of the form each and every time so is there any code so that i can change the label of one form from the other form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually pass the value from form 1 to form 2.

E.g. if your `Form1` shows `Form2`, you could do:

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
    // ...

    private void button2_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        using ( var form2 = new Form2() )
        {
            form2.LabelValue = this.label1.Text;
            form2.ShowDialog(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Write a public property `LabelValue` in `Form2` that maps to the label in `Form2`.